# Failed to find the "zip" utility program in path whilst packaging dotnet6 aws lambda project in TeamCity

Tags: .net, linux, aws-lambda, teamcity

I have a dotnet6 lambda project that I'm trying to package and obtain a build.zip in TeamCity. Currently, I have a TeamCity build step running the command `dotnet lambda package [project stuff here]`, everything works fine until the last step, which is to zip up the contents however I get hit with a `Failed to find the "zip" utility program in path. This program is required to maintain Linux file permissions in the zip archive.` log message failing the build step.

Comment: The error message you are getting is because in your step, you are calling `zip` as an executable and it can't be found. The machine the step is running either does not have the tool installed or the `PATH` environment variable does not have a path that contains the executable.

Comment: In the script I'm not calling `zip`, `dotnet lambda package` calls it. After looking at a similar post it seemed like AWS had their own zip.exe but I don't know how to get it or where it goes.


After trying this on my local machine, AWS's `zip.exe` was in some folders in Visual studio about the AWS Toolkit extension so it can't be that. Even after uninstalling the extension and their `zip.exe` being removed, still `dotnet lambda package` works on my local machine but not on TeamCity